# How can I store object has a multiple strings from firebase database using swift3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have object named myArray in firebase database structure and it has a multiple lines of strings as [a , b and c ] like this [image: My DB Structure] how can I display this object in my Table View ,When I run it its coming in My Debug like this [image: My Debug] but its not appears in my simulator its appease like this [image: My Simulator],I am using swift 3

This is My Code :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TestTable: UITableViewController {

var arrayList = [test]()

var Ref = FIRDatabaseReference()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Ref=FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    Ref.child("Users").child("Test").observe(.childAdded ,with: { (snapshot) in

        if  let User = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]{

            let Add = test()

            Add.setValuesForKeys(User)

            self.arrayList.append(Add)


            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\(snapshot.value)")

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    })


 }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return arrayList.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return arrayList[section].myArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as!TestTableCell

    let hh = indexPath.section

    cell.myTestView.text = (arrayList[hh].myArray as AnyObject) as? String

    cell.titleText.text = arrayList[hh].title


    return cell


 }


 }
```

and this is My Class :

```
 class test : NSObject {


var myArray : NSArray = []

var title : String?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your myArray is not array of string, it's dictionary. So if you want value of a,b and c in cell.myTestView.text. Then you need to run loop to get all a,b and c in cell.myTestView.text.

```
var string = ""

for (key, value) in arrayList[hh].myArray
{
    print("\(key) -> \(value)")
    string = string + "\n\(key) -> \(value)"
}

cell.myTestView.text = string
```

update your line `cell.myTestView.text = (arrayList[hh].myArray as AnyObject) as? String` with above code.

Comment: I have error in this line (for (key, value) in arrayList[hh].myArray) says [Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript']

Comment: add 'as! [String:String]' to arrayList[hh].myArray. Or make myArray as [String:String]. replace line 
var myArray : NSArray = [] in text class to 
var myArray = [String:String]()